# Marginalizing a product of multivariate normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I am trying to derive a distribution shown in the paper [Probabilistic Non-linear Principal Component Analysis with Gaussian Process Latent Variable Models](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/lawrence05a/lawrence05a.pdf).

We are given 
\begin{align}
p(x) &= \mathcal{N}(x | 0, I) \\
p(y | x , W , \beta) &= \mathcal{N}(y|Wx, \beta^{-1}I),
\end{align}
where $\beta$ is a scalar.

I want to show

$$
\int p(y|x,W,\beta)p(x)dx = \mathcal{N}(y| 0, WW^\top + \beta^{-1}I).
$$

To do this I thought I would use the method decribed [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/more_on_gaussians.pdf), which utilize "completion of squares", which states

$$
\frac{1}{2}z^\top A z + b^\top z + c = \frac{1}{2}(z + A^{-1}b)A(z + A^{-1 }b) + c - \frac{1}{2}b^\top A^{-1}b
$$

Then I have that

\begin{align}
p(y| x, W, b)p(x) 
&\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}((y-Wx)^\top(\beta I)(y-Wx) + x^\top I x)) \\
&= \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\beta y^\top y - \beta y^\top Wx - \beta(Wx)^\top y + \beta(Wx)^\top Wx + x^\top x)) \\
&= \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\beta y^\top  y + 2(- \beta y^\top W) x + x^\top(\beta W^\top W + I )x)) \\
&= \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\beta y^\top y +\beta y^\top W x -\frac{1}{2}x^\top(\beta W^\top W + I )x)\\
&= \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^\top(\beta W^\top W + I )x +(\beta y^\top W) x-\frac{1}{2} \beta y^\top y) \text{, apply completion of squares} \\
&=\exp(-\frac{1}{2} (x + (\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1} (\beta y^\top W)^\top)^\top(\beta W^\top W + I)(x + (\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1} (\beta y^\top W)^\top) \\
&-\frac{1}{2}\beta y^\top y -\frac{1}{2}(\beta y^\top W)(\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1}(\beta y^\top W)^\top)\\
&= \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (x + (\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1} (\beta y^\top W)^\top)^\top(\beta W^\top W + I)(x + (\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1} (\beta y^\top W)^\top) \\
& \cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{2}y^\top(\beta I + \beta W(\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1}\beta W^\top) y) \\
&\implies \text{covariance of marginal is } (\beta I + \beta W(\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1}\beta W^\top)^{-1}
\end{align}

from which I don't see how to get $WW^\top + \beta^{-1}I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have the covariance of the marginal slightly wrong - the plus sign should be a minus, as you need to add the extra term to complete the square and subtract the same term to compensate. Thus the marginal covariance is
$$(\beta I \color{red}{-} \beta W(\beta W^\top W + I)^{-1}\beta W^\top)^{-1}$$

You can then use the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) where 
$$(A+UCV)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U\;\left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U\right)^{-1}VA^{-1}$$
setting $A=\beta^{-1}I$, $U=W$, $C=I$ and $V=W^\top$ results in
$$(\beta^{-1}I+WW^\top)^{-1}=\beta I-\beta W(I+\beta W^\top W)^{-1}\beta W^\top$$
Inverting both sides leads to the desired result
$$(\beta I-\beta W(\beta W^\top W+I)^{-1}\beta W^\top)^{-1}=WW^\top+\beta^{-1}I$$